# Установка epson stylus tx209 на Debian

Tags: debian, принтер

Не могу установить сабдевый принтер. Настроен cups, cupsys, установлены все пакеты, ставил драйвер последней версии. Всё устанавливалось штатно, но принтер видится только в lsusb. В общем, не могу печатать. Подскажите, как установить.

debian 6.0.4

Answer (score 1):

[Настройка принтера в Debian](http://wiki.debian.org/ru/SystemPrinting)